# Update Listview which contains Row and Section

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I have 2 components which are CalendarList and CalendarListItem. I use Listview to displays 10 records in CalendarListItem at the first load and it will add more 10 records when user scroll down.

I meet trouble when try to update Listview containing Row and Section to append next 10 records when user scroll down to the end of list. I have searched and applied hints but most of questions relating with rows only that not work for me.

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({
                     rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2,
                     sectionHeaderHasChanged: (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2,
                }); 
        this.state = {
                eventData: [],
                eventDatas: [],
                dataBlob: {},
                dataSource: {},
                dataBlog: [],
                refreshing: false,
                page: 1
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
          this.loadEventData(); 
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadEventData();
    }

loadEventData() {
    eventState = this.props.eventtop;


    console.log('NEW DATA', eventState);

        const tempDataBlob = this.state.dataBlob;

           this.state.eventData = this.props.eventtop;

            this.state.eventData.forEach(item => {
                const event = item;
                const date = new Date(item.EventDate);
                const group = dateFormat(date, 'mmmm yyyy');
                if (currentGroup !== group) {
                    currentGroup = group;
                    currentIndex++;
                    this.state.eventDatas.push({ divider: currentGroup, data: [] });     
                }
               this.state.eventDatas[currentIndex].data.push(event); 
               tempDataBlob[this.state.eventDatas[currentIndex].divider] = this.state.eventDatas[currentIndex].data;
               this.setState({
                   dataBlob: tempDataBlob
               });
            });

        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.ds.cloneWithRowsAndSections(this.state.dataBlob)
        });
        console.log('FUCKING DATA', this.state.dataBlob);
    }


renderRow(rowData) {
        return (               
                  <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={() => {
                        if (window.width <= 600) {
                             Actions.calendarDetail({ eventtop: rowData });
                        } else if (window.width > 600) {      
                                this.props.getEventd(rowData);
                              this.passState.bind(this.props.eventItems);
                        }
                             }}
                    >
                        <View>
                            <Text style={styles.evenType}>
                                 {rowData.EventType}
                             </Text>
                             <Text style={{ ...styles.contentStyle, ...styles.contenStyle2 }}>
                                {dateFormat(rowData.EventDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')}
                             </Text>
                             <Icon
                                name='chevron-thin-right'
                                style={styles.iconStyle}
                             />
                             <View 
                                style={styles.titleStyle}
                             >
                                <Text style={styles.contentStyle}>  
                                {rowData.Title}
                             </Text>
                             </View>                          
                         </View>                 
                    </TouchableOpacity>    
        );
}
renderSectionHeader(sectionData, sectionId) {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text style={styles.timeStyle}>
                      {sectionId}
            </Text>
        </View>
    );
}

    render() {
        return (
                <ListView
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    enableEmptySections
                    dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderRow={data => this.renderRow(data)}
                    renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
                    onEndReached={this.props.onEndReached}
                    renderFooter={this.props.renderFooter}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={30}
                />


        );
    }
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you to switch FlatList, while you haven't got into listview and its logic. FlatList handles most of the tasks that users have to manually do in listview.

Comment: Well, does FlatList support Sticky header now? I intended to switch to FlatList last week, but I read from this article and he said Flat List never support Sticky Header: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/a3457486e39dc752799b1103ebe606224a8e8d32#commitcomment-21097746

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution yesterday. Actually I need to create another Action Creator and place it inside CalendarListItem, that action will return state which is new data then I concat old data with that new data. Done!